# Can I Anonyminze my bitvise ssh tunnel session?

Tags: windows, ssh, security, ssh-tunnel

Is there a way to anonyminze my bitvise ssh client session that way the ssh server I connect to doesn't log my real IP address? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no such option in client.

However, there are several workarounds:

- You can use VPN or some SOCKS or maybe some other SSH server for accessing server, in that case system will log IP address of VPN.
- You can configure TCP proxy on SSH server that forwards connections from one chosen port to ssh port. In that case SSH server will log localhost ip.
- You can just clean logs when you connected to server. In case server works on some *nix system you can use some wtmp cleaner and [disable logging](https://serverfault.com/questions/306433/linux-disable-wtmp-utmp-sshd-ip-logging-and-any-mentions-of-ip-that-does-remot) of `auth` and `authpriv`.
- You can patch ssh server to not logging your IP at all.